# Python importing module when calling the script by another script

Tags: python, path

I have the following [python structure
   directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbgqO.png)

In `login_logout_test.py` I use the following imports and everything works fine when I run this script (all the modules are imported properly)

```
import sys, os
parentPath = os.path.abspath("..")
if parentPath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, parentPath)
import common_test_functions as cts
from functions import login_logout_functions as llf
```

But when this script (`login_logout_test.py`) is called by `CommandRunner.py` this error occurs:

> No module named 'common_test_functions'

Comment: When the script is called by CommandRunner.py, the parent dir is relative to  CommandRunner.py, not the parent dir of login_logout_test.py

Comment: I understand that, but I want to make the importation of scripts in such a way, that the **login_logout_test.py** runs properly by itself or called by **CommandRunner.py**

Comment: Try  to  use  one  dot instead of two

Comment: Still doesn't work. I thought if I include the grand parent folder, this import `from tests import common_test_functions as cts` would work, but it doesn't. 
Error: _ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests'_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I have contrived a solution to my own problem:

```
import sys, os
from selenium import webdriver
# adding path to common_test_functions to the sys.path
# so this module could be invoked
parentPath = os.path.abspath("..\\..")
if parentPath not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(parentPath)
from functions import login_logout_functions as llf
from tests import common_test_functions as cts
```

Also there is a file, that holds necessary for the script parameters. Here is the code to have this file path in both cases (running this script by itself or calling it by another script):

```
parameters_directory_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parameters_file_name = "login_logout_test_parameters.tsv"
parameters_file_path = os.path.join(parameters_file_path, parameters_file_name)
```

If someone has a better one, please post it.

Thank you in advance.

Stefan